# SQL Server Joins Beginner simple join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

**dbo.orders**:

- customerid
- orderid

**dbo.customerprofiletbl**:

- customerid
- customername

I am attempting to put together a join but I am failing:

```
select 
    dbo.orders.customerid AS orde, 
    dbo.customerprofiletbl.customerid AS cust
from 
    dbo.customerprofiletbl
left join
    orde on cust
```

Help?

Comment: yes, you need to actually give it a join condition. For instance `ON someColumnFromTheFirstTable = someColumnFromTheSecondTable`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

```
select 
  orde.customerid AS orde, 
  cust.customerid AS cust
from dbo.customerprofiletbl cust
LEFT JOIN dbo.orders orde on cust.customerid = orde.customerid
```

You are getting the values from the columns using the table alias's you created (`orde` and `cust`) and calling the new columns the same name, but that doesn't matter - you could have done `as OrderCustomerId` for example..

When joining, you join one table to another, and you can use the table alias's to make things easier. When you join 2 tables, you have to tell it when columns to use to create the join on - using the alias's helps here.

Answer (score 0):

You have some of your query a little backwards. You should be putting the table name of the joining table in the join statement (you can still alias it there), and then in the list if select columns you can also use just the alias:

```
SELECT
    orde.customerid,
    cust.customerid
FROM
    dbo.customerprofiletbl cust
LEFT JOIN
    dbo.orders orde
    ON
    cust.customerid = orde.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select dbo.orders.customerid AS orde, 
  dbo.customerprofiletbl.customerid AS cust
from dbo.customerprofiletbl
LEFT JOIN orde on dbo.customerprofiletbl.customerid  = orde.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems you are in wrong direction. But your query is like
   `Select o.customerid as orde, cpt.customerid AS cust from dbo.orders o left join dbo.customerprofiletbl cpt on o.customerid=cpt.customerid`

CustomerProfiletbl should be on left side as there is no way order can be done without customer

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the columns where join is made
Just add the ON Clause

```
select 
dbo.orders.orderid
 dbo.customerprofiletbl.customerid
 Dbo.customerprofiletbl.customername
from dbo.customerprofiletbl
    LEFT JOIN dbo.orders ON     dbo.customerprofiletbl.customerid =     dbo.orders.customerid
```